# Windows Server 2008R2 crash every hour

Tags: windows-server-2008, server-crashes

I have a Windows Server 2008R2 which crash every 1 hour.
The server is physical and is provided by fasthosts but I can access the server(out of the country).
So I checked for Event Viewer before crash and didn't find anything.
I checked in Task Scheduler for any task that is running every hour but again I didn't find anything. 
Fasthosts console is now working at all but when the server crashes I can see a screenshot which says that there is no signal.
Any ideas what is causing that?

**UPDATE:**
I was connected with RDP on the server and it was starting to slow down.
Then Task Manager Hang and I wasn't able to log out or open a browser. After 1 hour I wasnt able to connect on the server

Comment: Sounds very much like a hardware failure. Is it on the dot every hour? My first thought would be RAM, which is hard for you to test without physical access. If it has SMART capabilities, you can try to run that to see if there are any HDD failures, if nothing else to rule it out.

Comment: Do you get a crash dump? Or can you configure the system to take a crash dump?

Comment: Yes I did but I wont get any crash dump

Comment: What evidence do you have of an actual crash? As opposed to network issues / connectivity issues / the server hanging?

Comment: Server is unresponsive for some time then I am not able even to connect on it. Then hard restart from the website.

Answer (score 2):

When a 180 day trial Windows Server 2008R2 license expires it will start rebooting every hour.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2021579

You should also see in your log:

```
Log Name:    Application
Source:      WLMS
Event ID:    100
Description: The license period for this installation of Windows
             has expired. The operating system will shut down every hour.
```

Comment: No it's not that

Comment: You using Hyper-V? If so double check the host license in use - it could be a 180 trial on a regular 2008R2 install with the Hyper-V role enabled instead of the stripped down Hyper-V install with the free license.

Comment: No it's not Hyper-V.